# Trying to solve a system of equation

Tags: equation-solving

I am trying to solve 3 equations 3 unknown system on Mathematica in order to get numerical results for my three variables `x,y,z` but the software is always on the `Running...` status and never gives a result. (It does not give an error message neither. Mathematica stays actionless and after I smust reinitialize it.)

```
 parametres = {
   σ -> 1.5
 , α -> 0.3
 , β -> 0.6
 , ρ -> 0.02
 , δ -> 0.05
 , ϕ -> 0.8
 };
```

After the calibration, I use

```
sol11 = Solve[
 {
  ((α y - ρ) (α - 1))/(σ (α - β - 1)) == x 
  , (β x)/(α - 1) + y^(α - 1) == z
  , x ((β (1 - σ))/(1 - α) + (βy^α)/(ϕ z)) == ρ
  }
 , \{x, y, z}] /. parametres // Simplify
```

What could be the problem ? Does it mean that there does not exist a result ?

Comment: Your code is currently trying to find a symbolic result first, and then substituting the numerical values into it. You might have better luck if you do the parameter substitution first: `Solve[{...}/.parametres, {x, y, z}]`. Alternatively, if that doesn't work either, you can try `FindRoot`.

Comment: @MarcoB Thanks so much. Solve did not work but FindRoot worked perfectly !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
parametres = {σ -> 1.5, α -> 0.3, β -> 0.6, ρ -> 
     0.02, δ -> 0.05, ϕ -> 0.8} // Rationalize;
```

Your third equation contains `(βy^α)` there needs to be a space as in `(β y^α)`

```
eqns = {((α y - ρ) (α - 
           1))/(σ (α - β - 1)) == 
      x, (β x)/(α - 1) + y^(α - 1) == z, 
     x ((β (1 - σ))/(1 - α) + (β \
y^α)/(ϕ z)) == ρ} /. parametres // Simplify;
```

Restrict the domain to `Reals`

```
sol11 = Solve[eqns, {x, y, z}, Reals] // N
```

> {{x -> 0.082946, y -> 0.836879, z -> 1.06166}}

Since `Rationalize` was used to provide exact numbers for the parameters, `Solve` provides an exact solution in terms of `Root` objects.  `//N` was used to convert these to numerical values. Verifying the result:

eqns /. sol11[[1]]

{True, True, True}

Comment: Thanks for the clear presentation. I did not think in this way.

Answer (score 3):

I guess the [FindInstance](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindInstance.html) function does the job:

```
FindInstance[{((α y - ρ) (α - 1))/(σ (α - β - 1)) == x
, (β x)/(α - 1) + y^(α - 1) == z
, x ((β (1 - σ))/(1 - α) + (β y^α)/(ϕ z)) == ρ} 
/. parametres, {x, y, z}, Reals]
```

> {{x -> 0.082946, y -> 0.836879, z -> 1.06166}}

Comment: Thanks for the use of this command to which I was not familiar.